# Django - Ignore certain fields on update depending on condition

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-views

#### Description:

The goal is to update **all** `Spotlight` fields on `PUT/PATCH` (`update/partial update`) if its `status` is `YELLOW`.

If `status` is `RED || GREEN`, it should update **only** its `status` and **ignore** any other fields. The workaround presented here is kind of smelly and it produces misleading responses when using `PUT`.

Is there any Django way to achieve this better than the presented workaround?

#### Workaround:

```
if instance.state == instance.STATE_YELLOW:
    custom_data = request.data
else:
    custom_data = {'state': request.data['state']}
```

#### Full code:

```
from stoplight.filters import StoplightFilter
from stoplight.models import Stoplight
from stoplight.permissions import (
    IsSuperuserOrReadOnly
)
from stoplight.serializers import StoplightSerializer
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.mixins import CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet


class StoplightViewSet(GenericViewSet, CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin):
    """
    API endpoint for Stoplights
    """

    queryset = Stoplight.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StoplightSerializer
    filter_class = StoplightFilter
    search_fields = ('name',)
    permission_classes = (IsSuperuserOrReadOnly,)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Updates Stoplight state
        """
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        
        if instance.state == instance.STATE_YELLOW:
            custom_data = request.data
        else:
            custom_data = {'state': request.data['state']}
        
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=custom_data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
            instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['partial'] = True
        return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I can't really think of a "clean" way of doing that - but you could leverage the `__init__` method of your `SpotlightSerializer` and use that to manipulate the [`read_only_fields`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields) of the serializer based on the `instance` and its `instance.state`, that way you should be able to use the regular `UpdateModelMixin`

Comment: The idea here is that RED and GREEN stoplights should never change anything else than the status right? In that case the correct way to deal with this would be to make the Stoplight model raise an exception on `save`.

If you want to _ignore_ some parameters under some conditions, then the only way is to ignore them like you do, but it's a hack (not against django, but against REST)

Comment: Ultimately, I decided to move that login to the `Serializer` so that the ``ViewSet` extends `UpdateModelMixin`. Then I added a `UpdateSerializer` which handled all that logic, raising exceptions (`HTTP 400`) when things go against the requirement.